# Rendering MathML in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, mathml

I have MathML that I need to render in my LaTeX document. Is there a recommended way of doing so?

So far, from googling, I've found [MathParser](http://www.tilman.de/programme/mathparser/index_en.html) - a Java converter. But I was hoping there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: How elaborate are the MathML fragments that you need to render? It might be possible to write a simple converter if they only use a limited subset of MathML.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Are MathML and LaTeX similar enough to easily write a simple converter for? It may be complex fragments (data from a client) but it might still be manageable to write one.

Comment: Is it content math or presentation mathml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get TeX to parse the MathML, see for example xmltex, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xmltex which comes with some mathml setup, however I wouldn't do it that way these days, I'd convert the MathML using XSLT, see for example pmml2tex which is available on [github](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex)

Comment: googlecode is down, but `pmml2tex` is available on github: https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I should probably search for all old googlecode links and update the answers, thanks.

Comment: You should try ConTeXt ;)

Comment: @HenriMenke I'd expect my xslt gets a closer approximation to my understanding of MathML than any other convertor:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've `successfully` used your stylesheet (and some other tools available online) - and agree with the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the most success with xsltml: http://xsltml.sourceforge.net